# AutoMapper,try and catch mapping

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch, automapper

I have created a map, however.. a few of the source properties will from time to time throw an exception (Dont ask me why someone has decided to make the "get" throw exceptions if its null..but well..)
This causes some problems when AutoMapper tries to map the properties, is there anyway to try and catch the exception with in the mapping and if it enter the cache, then simply assign a default value to the destination-property?

Br,
Inx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered

```
Automapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Source,Dest>().BeforeMap(Action<Source, Dest> beforeMapAction)`
```

?

From https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Before-and-after-map-actions

> Occasionally, you might need to perform custom logic before or after a map occurs. These should be a rarity, as it's more obvious to do this work outside of AutoMapper. You can create global before/after map actions:
>
> ```
> Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Dest>()
> .BeforeMap((src, dest) => src.Value = src.Value + 10)
> .AfterMap((src, dest) => dest.Name = "John");
> ```
>
> Or you can create before/after map callbacks during mapping:
>
> ```
> int i = 10;
> Mapper.Map<Source, Dest>(src, opt => {
> opt.BeforeMap((src, dest) => src.Value = src.Value + i);
> opt.AfterMap((src, dest) => dest.Name = HttpContext.Current.Identity.Name);
> });
> ```
>
> The latter configuration is helpful when you need contextual information fed into before/after map actions.

First, you have to add your property to ignore list and after that use before map.

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Source,Dest>().
ForMember((src => src.PropertyWithException), opt => opt.Ignore()).
BeforeMap((src,dest)=>
{
    try
    {
        dest.PropertyWithException = src.PropertyWithException;
    }
    catch
    {
        dest.PropertyWithException = some_default_value;
    }
});
```

Comment: Hmm.. Im not quite sure of how to use that.. do you mean that I could set the values of the properties thats currently throwing an exception to a default value with an action in the .BeforeMap-method.. and then just chain a bunch of ForMember after that as usual?